# Parse date in javascript issues

Tags: javascript, extjs

I get such date in javascript

```
var val = "1960-05-15T20:00:00"
```

But if I do

```
var date = new Date(val);
```

The data I get is one day later:

```
1960-05-16 // I use this to obtain it: Ext.Date.format(new Date(val), 'm/d/Y')
```

Can you help me how to parse this date? and get correct date with 1960-05-15?

Comment: I don't have that issue... just tried it, try making it an iso string...

Comment: @CallumLinington Maybe it is some time zone related so I would like to know how to correct that

Comment: Use ISO format :)

Comment: @CallumLinington I don't control how I receive the date string

Comment: Do they send any timezone information with that date?

Comment: @CallumLinington The string I showed above is all I have

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/135562/discussion-between-callum-linington-and-user400500).

Answer (score 2):

Your date format is **ISO 8601** represented as the local time with an offset to UTC appended.
The `Ext.Date` singleton support this format with the `c` flag.

```
var parsedDate = Ext.Date.parse('1960-05-15T20:00:00', 'c');
var dateStr = Ext.Date.format(parsedDate, 'Y-m-d');
// "1960-05-15"
```

Have a look at the [Sencha ExtJs 6.2.1 documentation Ext.Date](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.1/classic/Ext.Date.html) for further informations.

Answer (score 0):

You can use native JS to accomplish the output of the Date object in to this format `yyyy-mm-dd`

Like so:

```js
var val = '1960-05-15T20:00:00';
var d = new Date(val);
var date = d.getFullYear() + '-' +  ('0' + (d.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2) + '-' + ('0' +  d.getDate()).slice(-2);
console.log(date);
```

Answer (score 0):

When you do

```
var a = new Date(someDate)
```

variable a contains date according to your local timezone.

If you want date in same format as you entered , use toISOString method

```
var a = (new Date(someDate)).toISOString()
```

Answer (score -1):

My recommendation would be, you can only assume the timezone from where the date is coming from. If you know exactly where that date is coming from, a.k.a London, New York, Sidney, etc... then you can use momentjs to set the [UTC offset](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/manipulating/utc-offset/)

```
var val = "1960-05-15T20:00:00"

// these are equivalent
moment(val).utcOffset("+08:00");
moment(val).utcOffset(8);
moment(val).utcOffset(480);
```

So the OP has said they're in

> Tbilisi, Georgia GMT + 4.00

so

```
moment(val).utcOffset("+04:00");
```